# How to add description to @ApiTags for swagger in NestJS?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I want to add desription for block of api.

I have tried:

```
@ApiOperation({
  description: 'Operation description'
})
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Adding description on method level**

```js
@ApiOperation({ summary: 'Operation description' })
```

Check here: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/migration-guide#breaking-changes

**Adding tag on class level (controller)**

```js
@ApiTags('MyTag')
```

This will create a collapsible block with all methods underneath it.

Check here: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/decorators

Comment: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when ca
lled as an expression.

8 @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Operation description' })

Comment: I have this error

Comment: `@ApiOperation` is meant to be used on methods and can't be used on classes. I think what you are looking for is `@ApiTags()`.
Check here: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/decorators

Comment: No such functionality

Comment: I want to add description to @ApiTags('')

Comment: Adding a description to the tag doesn‘t seem to be supported by NestJS at the moment.

Answer (score 10):

To improve previous answer:
You can add tag description on initial step

```
new DocumentBuilder()
.setTitle('API with NestJS')
...
.addTag('SomeTag1', 'Tag description 1')
.addTag('SomeTag2', 'Tag description 2')
```

And then use tag on class level (controller)

```
@ApiTags('SomeTag1')
```